# Hosting a site on Amazon S3, URL keeps redirecting

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-s3, amazon-route53

I am trying to use Amazon S3 to host my webiste. I have the domain registered though namecheap. 
Whenever I navigate to `mywebsite.com` the URL in the browser changes to `http://mywebsite.com.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/`.
I would like the URL in the browser to stay unchanged, but really have no idea how to fix it. 
Here are few screenshots of my setup. I'd appreciate any help.

**namecheap DNS setup** [image: namecheap DNS setup]

**Route 53 setup** [image]

Answer (score 2):

DNS has a limit. The top level of a domain must be an A record, it cannot be a CNAME. For example, `serverfault.com` cannot be a CNAME, it must be an IP address, because that’s what the value of A records are. IP addresses.
Try changing the A record to point to an IP address (could be the IP address of `s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com` & then add another ALIAS record if needed.

Comment: Where is OP referencing an apex?

Comment: I thought that's what he mentioned when he said mywebsite.com.

Comment: You're right. I missed that part :)

Answer (score 2):

According to the guides, Amazon advices you to create two buckets:

- mywebsite.com
- www.mywebsite.com

One of those buckets will be used to host the actual site (Enable web hosting), the other is used as a domain redirect (Redirect all requests to another host name). Both buckets are then added to Route53 in the same manner, using an ALIAS.

You can find more information in [this detailed guide](http://chadthompson.me/2013/06/21/adding-redirects-to-amazon-s3-hosted-web-sites/) and [here](http://chadthompson.me/2013/05/06/static-web-hosting-with-amazon-s3/).

Answer (score 0):

My problem ended up being caused by DNS caching. Running `ipconfig /flushdns` from the command line as well as flushing the cache in Chrome and Firefox did the trick.